# Installing .apk in android emulator reports 0x501 error while using GPU Emulation with OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator, apk, arcgis

I am trying to run the **ArcGIS for Android** samples in Android Emulator. Based on the [ArcGIS recommendation](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/05/02/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-android-v1-1-supports-android-emulator/), I have installed the **Intel HAXM** and enabled the **GPU Emulation** as well.

One of my machine having 3GB RAM running the .apk in Emulator without issues. But another machine having 2GB RAM, reporting the below console output while running the application. It seems the application has been **installed with ERRORS**, and I can see the application layout **without MAP** and its not responding to me.

Please suggest me, is it anything related to insufficient hardware or am I missing any software configuration things to get it worked?

Thanks in advance!

```
[2012-08-17 12:07:07 - GeometryEditor] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-08-17 12:07:07 - GeometryEditor] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-08-17 12:08:32 - GeometryEditor] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-08-17 12:08:32 - GeometryEditor] Uploading GeometryEditor.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-08-17 12:09:20 - GeometryEditor] Installing GeometryEditor.apk...
[2012-08-17 12:09:42 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1911 error 0x501
[2012-08-17 12:09:42 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1380 error 0x501
[2012-08-17 12:09:42 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetAttribLocation:825 error 0x501
[2012-08-17 12:09:42 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1911 error 0x501
[2012-08-17 12:09:42 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1380 error 0x501
[2012-08-17 12:09:42 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetAttribLocation:825 error 0x501
[2012-08-17 12:09:42 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1380 error 0x501
.............
.............
.............
[2012-08-17 12:10:27 - GeometryEditor] Success!
[2012-08-17 12:10:27 - GeometryEditor] Starting activity com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.geometryeditor.GeometryEditor on device emulator-5554
[2012-08-17 12:10:30 - GeometryEditor] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.geometryeditor/.GeometryEditor }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting OpenGL error 501 (GL_INVALID_VALUE) with what looks like every function related to your shaders.

I will guess that the shaders included with the program are not compiling, and that there is no error checking/validation of the shaders when they are compiled and linked, so it's proceeding with a broken program. Different GPUs are somewhat finicky about the shader source they will accept, so it doesn't seem surprising at all that a program that works on one computer would stop working on another.

Do you have the source code to this project, that you could edit? It's possible that it is easy to fix, if you print the debug messages from the shader.